# WebAudioApi StreamSource

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'd like to use the WebAudioApi with streams. Prelistening is very important and can't be realized when I have to wait for each audio-file to be downloaded.

Downloading the entire audio data is not intended, but the only way it can get it work at the moment:

```
request.open('GET', src, true);
request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
request.onload = function() {
  var audioData = request.response;
  //audioData is the entire downloaded audio-file, which is required by the audioCtx anyway
  audioCtx.decodeAudioData(audioData, function(buffer) {
    source.buffer = buffer;
    source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    source.loop = true;
    source.play();
  },

  function(e){"Error with decoding audio data" + e.err});
}
request.send();
```

I found a possibility to use a stream, when requesting it from the navigator mediaDevices:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia ({audio: true, video: true})
.then(function(stream) {
    var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
    var source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    source.play();
```

Is it possible to use the xhr instead of the navigator mediaDevices to get the stream:

```
 //fetch doesn't support a range-header, which would make seeking impossible with a stream (I guess)
 fetch(src).then(response => {
    const reader = response.body.getReader();
    //ReadableStream is not working with createMediaStreamSource
    const stream = new ReadableStream({...})
    var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
    var source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    source.play();
```

It doesn't work, because the ReadableStream does not work with createMediaStreamSource.

My first step is realizing the functionality of the html-audio element with seek-functionality. Is there any way to get a xhr-stream and put it into an audioContext?

The final idea is to create an single-track-audio-editor with fades, cutting, prelistening, mixing and export functionality.

**EDIT:**

Another atempt was to use the html audio and create a SourceNode from it:

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = src;
var source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
//the source doesn't contain the start method now
//the mediaElement-reference is not handled by the internal Context-Schedular
source.mediaElement.play();
```

The audio-element supports a stream, but cannot be handled by the context-schedular. This is important in order to create an audio editor with prelistening functionality.

It would be great to reference the standard sourceNode's buffer with the audio-element buffer, but I couldn't find out how to connect them.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this problem before and have been working on a demo solution below to stream audio in chunks with the Streams API.  Seeking is not currently implemented, but it could be derived.  Because bypassing `decodeAudioData()` is currently required, custom decoders must be provided that allow for chunk-based decoding:

https://github.com/AnthumChris/fetch-stream-audio

Comment: Thanks for this information. I used the audio element and did the planning myself.

Comment: @marcel could you share your solution as a separate answer?